# In Chrome extension, content script does not receive message from background on initial load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script, browser-extension

In my Chrome extension, the content script is supposed to receive a message from the background script on page load. But when I open a new tab and enter URL https://example.com, it does not receive the message. However, it works on page reload.
Is it because page loaded from chrome://newtab?

```js
// background script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender) {
  if (message.action === "NOTIFY_CONTENT_SCRIPT_LOADED") {
    console.log(`### ACK content script in page: ${message.pageURL} and tab: ${sender.tab.url}`);

    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, { action: "CHANGE_BG" }, () => {
      console.log("### ACK changed BG color of client page");
      // do more stuff
    });
  }
});
```

```js
// content script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, _, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.action === "CHANGE_BG") {  // <---- This is not received on first page load
    document.body.style.background = "yellow";
    sendResponse();
  }
});

console.log("### Notifying background from page: " + location.href);
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "NOTIFY_CONTENT_SCRIPT_LOADED", pageURL: location.href });
```

Console log from background script:

```bash
### ACK content script in page: https://example.com/ and tab: chrome://newtab/
```

Please note that the `sender.tab.url` is `chrome://newtab/` instead of `https://example.com/`.
This is intermittently happening. That is, does not happen in some cases:

- when page is reloaded
- when browser inspect window is already opened

I have created an example extension with same issue: https://github.com/lazyvab/chrome-newtab-issue

---

Edit: Tried suggestion from comment -

> In case of multiple messages don't use sendMessage, but switch to chrome.runtime.connect.

```js
// content script
const bgPort = chrome.runtime.connect();
bgPort.onMessage.addListener((msg) => {
  console.log("### Received BG msg", msg);
});

// background script
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener((port) => {
  port.onDisconnect.addListener((...args) => {
    console.log("### disconnected port on tab", tabId, ...args);
  });

  console.log("### BG: sending ping to tab", tabId);
  port.postMessage({ action: "ping" });
});
```

I opened https://example.com in new tab and here is the result.

A screenshot from background page console:
[image: screenshot from background page console]

A screenshot from content script (page) console:
[image: screenshot from content script]

As can be seen in the screenshots, the port disconnects immediately after website loads and background script is not able to send messages using the port again.

Comment: It means the page was pre-rendered. Don't use chrome.tabs.sendMessage, use [sendResponse](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: @wOxxOm `sendResponse` can be used only when the message was initiated from content script. How can I do it when the message is to be sent asynchronously from background to content script when page was pre-rendered. Also, is there a way to detect if page was pre-rendered?

Comment: Your messaging cycle is initiated by the content script, which is why sendResponse will work and is the correct method. To respond asynchronously add `return true` as mentioned in the documentation. For more info on pre-rendering see https://developer.chrome.com/blog/extension-instantnav/

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the reference. In my case, I want to send message from background to content script and also run some logic in response. I updated example in the post.  It will be hard to sequence these if I pass messages in first sendResponse. I might need to send another message from content script to background in response to message received in sendResponse.

Comment: Your code still initiates messaging from the content script so you can rework it to use sendResponse. Currently you use sendResponse incorrectly (it does nothing useful). It should be used in the background script's onMessage to send the data back. Use the [documentation's](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) first snippet (sendMessage) and third snippet (onMessage) to rewrite the current code in the question.

Comment: In case of multiple messages don't use sendMessage, but switch to chrome.runtime.connect, see "long-lived connections" in the documentation.

Comment: fyi, i'm unable to reproduce the issue with your test repo.

Comment: @imlokesh It totally depends on the browser if it is pre-rendering the page for optimization. For me, it is happening most of the time.

Comment: @wOxxOm If I want to send a message from background to content script at a later stage using tabId and frameId (received in first message from content script), I realize it never reaches the active frame due to prerendering. How to make `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` work reliably for prerendered page?

Comment: Use chrome.runtime.connect from the content script, then you'll have a port to which you can send messages in both directions.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried your suggestion to use long-lived connection and I'm getting port disconnected event immediately on website load. Due to this, background is not able to communicate back to content script using the port. I have updated my post with code and screenshots.

Comment: It may be a bug in Chrome e.g. https://crbug.com/1178188.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally solve this issue by establishing a long-lived port connection between content script and background script in case of pre-rendered pages.

```js
// background.js
let clientPort = null;
let clientLoadSubscribers = [];

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener((port) => {
    const tabId = port.sender.tab.id;

    if (port.sender.documentLifecycle === "active") {
      clientPort = port;
      clientLoadSubscribers.forEach((subscriber) => subscriber());
      clientLoadSubscribers = [];
    }

    port.onDisconnect.addListener(() => {
      clientPort = null;

      chrome.tabs.executeScript(
        tabId,
        {
          code: "chrome.runtime.connect()",
        },
        () => {
          if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            // ignore
          }
        }
      );
    });
});

const sendMessageToClient = (tabId, ...restArgs) => {
  const send = () => chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, ...restArgs);

  if (clientPort) {
    send();
  } else {
    clientLoadSubscribers.push(send);
  }
};
```

```js
// content script
chrome.runtime.connect();
```

This way I could reliably send messages from background to content script using `sendMessageToClient()`.

Comment: P.S. - My reason to prefer `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` over `port.postMessage` is the flexibility to be able to target a particular frame and attach a callback which can be invoked asynchronously.